# Solving a first order second degree DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation problem. It asks to solve the following

$$y = x(y'-1) +y'^2$$

I substituted $y'=p$ and differentiated to get $$ 1 = p'(x+2p) $$

This is the point where I get stuck. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: $p(x)=-\frac 1 2 x -1$ is a solution obtained by treating $x$ as a   funcition of $p$ in your last equation.

Comment: I think the best we can do is the following:
$$y=x(y'-1)+y'^2\\
y=y'^2+xy'-x\\
y+\frac{x^2}{4}=\left(y'+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-x\\
u=y+\frac{x^2}{4}\\
u'=y'+\frac{x}{2}\\
(u')^2=u+x\\
u'=\pm\sqrt{u+x}\\
u=xv\\
u'=xv'+v\\
xv'+v=\pm|x|\sqrt{v+1}\\
xv'+v=x\sqrt{v+1}\\
v'+\frac{v}{x}=\sqrt{v+1}\\
t=v+1\\
t'+\frac{t}{x}-\sqrt t=\frac{1}{x}$$
I don't think this ODE has an elementary solution.